# Android camera 2 api SCALER_CROP_REGION invalidates manual focus

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2

I am working at an Android app to do focus bracketing for macro purposes. All works well, I can change the focus, exposure, capture pictures, etc. Today I wanted to implement a digital zoom to allow for precise focusing, and after doing that, using SCALER_CROP_REGION, my camera can't manually focus. It doesn't seem to be an issue with my code, since the same thing happens when using Open Camera (if I zoom in I can't focus after that). This ruins it for other applications too, and it only gets fixed after I restart the phone.
My phone is a Samsung A52, using Lineage OS (Android 13 based version).

Did anyone else encounter something like this?